# Pygmentize: No formatter found for name 'javascript'

Tags: ubuntu, jekyll, pygments

I'm trying to use Pygments to generate a CSS file formatted for JavaScript. I can do it fine for HTML by using:

```
pygmentize -S default -f html
```

However, when I try for JavaScript:

```
pygmentize -S default -f javascript
```

I get the following error:

```
No formatter found for name 'javascript'
```

How can I get Pygments to generate a CSS file for JavaScript? Thanks.

---

**Edit:** My goal is to generate the CSS needed to stylize Pygments-formatted `code` blocks. For example, when I run Jekyll with Pygments enabled, it will format my `code` blocks will all sorts of CSS classes. However, there is no CSS file to style those classes. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use Pygments.

Comment: What do you really want to do, it seems there is a misunderstanding of the 'formater' option. Do you mean 'lexer' ? Because if you want to display javascript code, you need the javascript lexer, not the formatter.

Comment: @BaptistePernet, I've edited my question to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what pygment does and the difference between the `lexer` and the `formatter`.

- `lexer` is used to parse the code you want to highlight, in jekyll, in the `{% highlight %}` command, you provide a lexer as argument: `ruby`, `python`, `javascript`, etc.
- `formatter` is the output format you want: `pdf`, `latex`, `html`, etc.

If you choose the html formatter, you will have **ONE CSS stylesheet** for all the languages that will be parsed using different `lexer`.

So to get this CSS, you can browser the web to find custom CSS (visit http://pygments.org/demo/ and use the combo box to select different style once your selected one demo). Or download the defaut style from http://pygments.org/media/pygments_style.css